# unable to set max_allowed_packet size to 2G

Tags: linux, mariadb

My mariadb10.2 database will not allow me to set the `max_allowed_packet` size to `2G`. It is set in the `my.cnf` file but keeps when I query it, it still sits at `1G`. I need `2G` for `mysqldump` to work. This was working correctly till an unexpected reboot occured.

```
my.cnf file[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
ssl = true
ssl-cert = /opt/certs/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key = /opt/certs/mysql/client-key.pem

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 16M

[mysqld]
basedir = /usr
bind-address = *
datadir = /mnt/mariadb/data/db
expire_logs_days = 10
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
key_buffer_size = 16M
log-error = /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
log_warnings = 4
max_allowed_packet = 2G
max_binlog_size = 100M
max_connections = 151
myisam_recover = BACKUP
pid-file = /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
plugin-load = auth_pam.so;auth_socket.so
port = 3306
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 16M
skip-external-locking
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
sql-mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
ssl = true
ssl-ca = /opt/certs/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert = /opt/certs/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /opt/certs/mysql/server-key.pem
thread_cache_size = 8
thread_stack = 256K
tmpdir = /tmp
user = mysql

[mysqld_safe]
log-error = /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
nice = 0
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 2G
quick
quote-names
```

Output when try to set temporarily:

> ```
> MariaDB [(none)]> set global max_allowed_packet=2147483684; ERROR 1231
> (42000): Variable 'max_allowed_packet' can't be set to the value of
> '2147483684'
> ```

My backups are ran out of cron using downloaded `automysqlbackup` script. All vars are managed by puppet which i have temp disabled to try to get this work again.

Comment: I'm, pretty sure that MariaDb allows for more than one config file.  It is possible that another config file is taking precedence and is basically overwriting your setting.  Check for other config files?

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to dump that needs the 2G?  A large video column?  A huge JSON?  What?

Answer (score 2):

You have to find another way to do you backups because max_allowed_packet can't be set to that value.

[The doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet) states that the max is 1GB.

Are you sure that you need a value that big? The value should be as big as your biggest blob, not the size of your database.
Having blobs that big can be tricky to handle.

Comment: yes, i need 2G. the developers is putting vid files in taht are larger than a gig

Answer (score 1):

(I'll address your question from many angles.  You may not realize how many issues you actually have.)

**Clarification**. So, you have rows bigger than the max allowed for `max_allowed_packet`, and hence for `mysqldump`?

**SELECT**. Can you even `SELECT` those rows?  If not, you are in an even bigger pickle.

**Backup**. Refer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2853#2853 for other ways to take a backup.  Or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161708/mysql-database-backup/161886#161886

**OOM**. How much RAM do you have?  I hope it is at least 8GB.  Otherwise, you are threatening to blow out RAM.

**Another setting**.  If you could get the packet limit to work, keep in mind that `innodb_log_file_size` must be at least 10 times that size.  (It is currently only 2G.)

**Pushback**.  Here is an argument to give to the devs...  If the 'vid' ('video'?) will be provided to end-users via a web server, then it would simpler all around (and solve the 1GB limit) by storing a *link* to a video *file*.  Then use `<img ...>` (or whatever) that will reach directly for the file.  This will bypass the database, making things faster and simpler.

**Chunking**. I was once forced to store huge things -- even bigger than 4GB.  My solution was to divide big data into 50KB chunks (arbitrarily) and have 2 tables -- one with the meta info, one with as many rows as needed to store all the chunks.  Messy code, messy database, stupid design.  Oh, and I ran into some other limitations.  Apache had some max on file size.

Comment: +1 for your pushback, this sounds like a developer that isn't thinking through the scaling consequences of their code. I agree that putting a video file (or frankly, any image) in a database field is wrong in a kind of fundamental way.